# Boolean as optional argument for copyWith

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to implement a copy constructir/method but one of the arguments is a `Boolean`. I looked around and there has been mention of using ?value to determine whether the value was supplied, but it does not compile:

```
class Model {
  final String id;
  final bool isEnabled;

  Model.copyFrom(Model data,
      {String id,
      bool isEnabled})
   : id = id ?? data.id,
     isEnabled = ?isEnabled ?? data.isEnabled);

}
```

If `isEnabled` is not supplied with `copyFrom` how do I tell it to use the one from `data`. The value whether being true or false needs to retained if it is not supplied.

`?isEnabled` raises a syntax error: Unexpected text '?'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
isEnabled = ?isEnabled ?? data.isEnabled
```

`??` already checks for `null`, there is no need for the `?` prefix.

This should do what you want

```
isEnabled = isEnabled ?? data.isEnabled
```

There is no need to treat boolean values differently.

What `?` or better `?.` does for example in

```
foo?.isEnabled
```

is, that it does not try to evaluate `isEnabled` when `foo` is `null` and just returns `null` instead, because `null` doesn't have an `isEnabled` getter and that would cause an exception.

Comment: And why not directly use `??=` operator?

Comment: "What does the ? prefix?" It produces a compilation error ;-) `And why not directly use ??= operator?` because in initializer list the first `isEnabled` refers to the field (`this.isEnabled`) and the 2nd to the parameter.

Comment: Oh I see. Didn't catch this difference.

Comment: It might look a bit weird but write access in initializer list is only allowed for fields and read access only for parameter values, so there is no ambiguity.

Comment: Coming from a C# background I thought this was my issue. Looking into it a bit more the right value is set.